# Spoofing System ID's with Python on Windows

Tags: python, windows, macos

I'll keep it as concise as possilble...

I'm in the process of making a spoofer on Windows (UUID, MAC, Serial Disk #). I've been able to fetch all of the correct items and randomize them, but I seem to have run into a dead end when it comes time to acutally implementing them. Does anyone know of any resources I can refer to that can help me with this issue?

Thanks for your time!

Ps. Already tried looking at the subprocesses documentation and didn't find anything that could help.